# Login attempts and the way to handle it

Tags: php, authentication

My method is currently to If the user credentials are wrong I do log an attempt but If the recaptcha (that is displayed after three failed attempts) are wrong, I do not.

When at 3 attempts failure I display reCaptcha

When at 5 attempts failure I lock the ip adress (15 minutes)

Or, well. I have set every attempt to last for 15 minutes.

What I am concern about is **If I should delete the attempts that were made when success**, **or If I shouldn't?** (After all is approximately 15 minutes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your security needs and policies. But consider that even though someone's "logged in", if the login was actually part of a distributed effort to break into the account, that other nodes in the distributed login effort might still be attempting other passwords. Should the account get locked out if there's still other failed attempts, even though someone actually managed to get in?

Comment: Well my Login attempts system is just bound to the ip-adress.

Answer (score 3):

I think that since the user complete (succesfully) the login, you should delete the attempts he made.

Answer (score 0):

I would never "delete" them. I would set a flag to alert someone to give that account further review. If after looking at the logs it looks like a simple mistake, ignore it. If you see a trend, aka consistent time intervals, many attempts, etc then I would take action to figure out what is happening.